# Solving $x^2+100=y^3$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, gaussian-integers

> Find all solutions to $x^2+100=y^3$ where $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Here's my progress so far:

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$, then $R:=\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a U.F.D. If $\alpha=x+10i$, then $\alpha\bar{\alpha}=y^3$.

If $\pi\in R$ is a prime element dividing $\alpha$ and $\bar\alpha$, then $\pi|(\alpha-\bar\alpha)=20i$, so $\pi$ divides one of $2$ or $5$ ($i\in R^{\times}$), which factor as follows in $R$:

- $2=i\pi_2^2$ where $\pi_2=1+i$, and $\bar\pi_2=-\pi_2$
- $5=\pi_5\bar\pi_5$ where $\pi_5=2+i$.

So the prime factorisation of $\alpha$ and $\bar\alpha$ look like follows:
$$\alpha=u\cdot\pi_2^a\pi_5^b\bar\pi_5^c\cdot\rho_1^{e_i}\cdots\rho_n^{e_n}\\
\bar\alpha=v\cdot\pi_2^a\bar\pi_5^b\pi_5^c\cdot\bar\rho_1^{e_i}\cdots\bar\rho_n^{e_n}\\
$$
where $a,b,c,e_i,n\in\mathbb{N}$; $u,v\in R^{\times}$; and $\rho_i$ primes in $R$ distinct from each other and the $\pi_p$.

Then: $y^3=uv\cdot\pi_2^{2a}\pi_5^{b+c}\bar\pi_5^{b+c}\cdot(\rho_1\bar\rho_1)^{e_1}\cdots(\rho_n\bar\rho_n)^{e_n}$, and since we're working in a U.F.D, each prime exponent on the right must be divisible by $3$, thus $3|a$, $3|e_i$ and $3|(b+c)$, i.e: $b+c\equiv 0\mod3$. So we have three cases:

- $b\equiv 0 \mod3 \implies c\equiv 0 \mod3$, and so $\alpha=\beta^3$ for some $\beta\in R$.
- $b\equiv 1 \mod3 \implies c\equiv 2 \mod3$, and so $\alpha\pi_5^2\bar\pi_5=\beta^3$ for some $\beta\in R$.
- $b\equiv 2 \mod3 \implies c\equiv 1 \mod3$, and so $\alpha\pi_5\bar\pi_5^2=\beta^3$ for some $\beta\in R$.

Letting $\beta=s+it$, we can 'easily' solve the first case:

$$\begin{align}x+10i&=(s+it)^3\\
&=s^3+3is^2t-3st^2-it^3\\
10&=t(3s^2-t^2)\end{align}$$

So $t|10$ and $s=\pm\sqrt{\frac13(\frac{10}{t}+t^2)}$, the only integer solution is $(s,t)=(\pm3,5)$, which yields $(x,y)=(\pm198,34)$

However, I'm struggling to solve the other two cases using the techniques I've familiar with... attempting to do the same thing in the second case got me this:

$$\begin{align}10x-50&=a^3-3ab^2\\100+5x&=3a^3b-b^3\end{align}$$

From this we have $250 = 6a^2b-2b^3-a^3+3ab^2$, which means $b-a\equiv 1 \mod3$... but I'm not sure how this is helpful. Wolfram $\alpha$ told me that there are more solutions to be found! Can I solve this system for $x$ or does the method not work in the last two cases? Should I be looking at ideals instead - though this seems unnecessary in a U.F.D? Are there other choices of $\alpha$ which unlock the other solutions?

Comment: When I solve Diophantine equations, I usually do the trial and error method: You first plug in a few values that meet the equation, and then once you begin to have no solutions, then you make a claim that there are no further solutions than $x$, say. So then you have all of the solutions to the equation, and you are done, (since by proof, you found there is exists no further solutions). You don't need to factor in $\mathbb Z[i]$, and stuff like that.

Comment: Well this fails, unless you want to solve this Diophantine equation using UFD's and $\mathbb Z[i]$, and which in this case, the problem is far more complex.

Comment: There are two small solutions which are easy to find.

Comment: keyword: Mordell's equation

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes, there's $(\pm5,5)$ and $(\pm30, 10)$. I suspect including $(\pm198, 34)$ that's all of them, but how do these smaller solutions arise from $\alpha\pi_5^i\bar\pi_5^j=\beta$, if at all? ($\{i,j\}=\{1,2\}$)

Comment: One of them is, in your last set of formulas, let $(x,a,b)=(5,0,-5)$

Comment: [Hemer (1954)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/arkiv-for-matematik/volume-3/issue-1/Notes-on-the-diophantine-equation-y2-k-x3/10.1007/BF02589282.pdf) could prove interesting.

Comment: @user3733558 Yes, Hemer is cited in the linked article in my answer. So he was the first with $k=-100$, I suppose?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: ah, sorry, I didn't check your reference. Will delete my comment in a minute. No idea if Hemer was first, could be, but I'm no math historian, so I'll refrain from uttering something that may very well end up looking stupid :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reference, Mordell's equation $y^2-k=x^3$ was solved for
$1\le |k|\le 100$ in

London, J. and Finkelstein, M.: On Mordell’s Equation $y^2-k=x^3$  Bowling Green State University, Bowling Green, Ohio (1973).

The case $k=-100$ gives $y^2+100=x^3$.

See also [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj8-vjitdPwAhWxxYUKHZcEC7IQFjAAegQIBBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcore.ac.uk%2Fdownload%2Fpdf%2F81198728.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3606yYSXC-HJrojTdhLufb) about the proof techniques. The reference [Hemer](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/arkiv-for-matematik/volume-3/issue-1/Notes-on-the-diophantine-equation-y2-k-x3/10.1007/BF02589282.pdf) lists all solutions
to $y^2+100=x^3$, namely
$$
(5,\pm 5),(10,\pm 30),(34,\pm 198).
$$

Comment: +1 of course. I think that mentioning [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/3600/x/1) may be worth while.